# Order of synchronous execution in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I got an issue while I was trying to test a Promise within an event listener. Everything is fine but the execution order.

```js
var test = document.querySelector('#test');
test.addEventListener('click',function(){
    Promise.resolve().then(function(){
        throw 'first';
    }).catch(function(er){
     console.log(er);
    });
});
test.addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log('second');
});
test.click();
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Why does the second listener finish earlier than the first listener?

Comment: `then`'s callbacks are invoked asynchronously to other code.

Comment: What do you mean by "finish"?

Comment: @zerkms How do you know that? Do you have any docs or something? Is that a bug or the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Bergi finish executing, actually.

Comment: It actually **is** in the standard: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen followed by http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enqueuejob

Comment: @Tresdin: The listener *does* finish executing. The other listeners do however not await any started asynchronous things (like a `then` callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like that as per the standard requirements:

> 8. Else if the value of promise's `[[PromiseState]]` internal slot is `"fulfilled"`,
>      a. Let value be the value of promise's `[[PromiseResult]]` internal slot.
>      b. Perform `EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs", PromiseReactionJob, «‍fulfillReaction, value»)`.
> 9. Else if the value of promise's `[[PromiseState]]` internal slot is `"rejected"`,
>      a. Let reason be the value of promise's `[[PromiseResult]]` internal slot.
>      b. Perform `EnqueueJob("PromiseJobs", PromiseReactionJob, «‍rejectReaction, reason»)`.

So, when a promise is resolved or rejected a corresponding callback is scheduled to be run later, asynchronously to the current execution.

References:

- [25.4.5.3.1 `PerformPromiseThen ( promise, onFulfilled, onRejected, resultCapability )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-performpromisethen)
- [8.4.1 `EnqueueJob (queueName, job, arguments)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enqueuejob)

Comment: Big thanks for the spec explanation. I think async executions are often applied to *long-running* operation (I/O, CPU intensive, etc). It doesn't make sense to implement it in this case. Do you have any idea why should `Promise.then` be async?

Comment: Well, I know that originally it was [`Promises/A+`](https://promisesaplus.com/) that it required it like that. And I'm not sure but there is a chance that the built-in Promises just adopted the behaviour. Personally I don't know what is the technical reason for them to be asynchronous. From the other hand - I do realise that *even* if they were synchonous for already resolved/rejected promises - you still would better not rely on that, since then you would have 2 different behaviours. So perhaps the original idea was to provide consistent behaviour.

Comment: @zerkms: Exactly, `then` callbacks are *consistently* (reliably) executed asynchronously.

Comment: @Tresdin: Well, simply if you don't have a long-running operation you shouldn't use promises. If you expect it to be synchronous, cannot use `then`.

Answer (score 1):

The second listener doesn't depend on first listener (promise), so they work asynchronously. Why do you separate them? You can simply use the following code

```
    Promise
        .resolve()
        .then(function(){
            throw 'first';
        })
        .catch(function(er){
            console.log(er);
        })
        .finally(function(er) {
            console.log('second');
        };
    });
```

Comment: I aldready know they're asynchronously executed. However, if `Promise.then` are synchronous, the execution order should be reversed.

Comment: @JaromandaX You didn't get my point. Event listeners are obviously asynchrounously executed, but `Promise.then`. I'm saying this because I think it's better to have a synchronous version of `Promise.then`.

Comment: I try to understand @Tresdin. Ok, we know that `Promise.resolve()` and `console.log('second')` are two asynchronous blocks of code. `Promise.resolve()` need more time to be executed, so that's why first you see `console.log('second')` running. And in this case if you want your `console.log('second')` confidently runs after first listener, you have to place it into `then, catch or finally` block, that's we call synchronous execution :) Hope I got your point @Tresdin